# Почему Symfony создает fluent interface в генерации сущностей?

Tags: php, symfony, fluent-interface

В статье о хорошей практике написания кода написано, что нужно избегать Fluent interface [ссылка на статью](https://github.com/peter-gribanov/clean-code-php)

Но при создании сущности в симфони через команду make:entity, как раз таки генерируется вместе с этим Fluent interface. Люди всегда пишут, что симфони это символ хорошего и чистого кода, и стоит ровнятся на их пакеты. Но если это плохая практика, тогда почему же симфони это генерирует?

Comment: _Хотя могут быть некоторые случаи в которых этот шаблон уменьшает многословность кода_

Comment: @DmitryKozlov но каков смысл делать это в сущности при её создании? Об этом был мой вопрос.

Comment: И в данной статье, и в обсуждении по ссылке из этой статьи, и вообще в инете признается, что fluent-интерфейс имеет смысл в паттерне "Строитель/Builder" (_Fluent interfaces make sense in some APIs, like the QueryBuilder , or in general builder objects, especially when it comes to putting together nodes into a hierarchical structure_). Entity собственно и является билдером